# What is this part called? (Rubber bolt/cap on top side of automatic transmission)

Tags: transmission, dodge, leak, neon

Picture:
[image]

From other angles:
[image]

The photos probably say it all, but for reference, I'll describe the situation:

While changing the radiator of my 2004 Dodge Neon (because its internal transmission cooler failed, causing the coolant and transmission fluid to mix together inside), out of nowhere, a heavy leak of dark red fluid suddenly appeared.

I pinpointed the leak to the mystery part circled above.

While the ones in the photos are metal, mine is rubber. The area it screws into is heavily rusted, and as a result, the mystery part fits wiggles loosely inside it.

Unless this is some kind of overflow valve, it seems fairly obvious the rust-induced looseness is what caused the leak.

I want to replace it, but I need to know its name first!

As you can see in the photos, it's located at the top of a crank-like mechanism emerging from the top side of the automatic transmission, right next to what I *believe* is the shifter cable. It appears to be some kind of cap or valve cover.

(Note: the 2nd-gen Dodge Neons in the photos are not mine -- I got them from YouTube.)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Transmission linkage bell crank arm?

Comment: I don't think so.... Could it be the transmission vent?

Comment: now that you know what it is please answer your own question and accept it as solved,you will get some reputation and we all will avoid this question popping up in the Q&A over and over as unsolved or un answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer -- it's the transmission vent.